# How do you check if NSURLRequest.URL is nil?

Tags: ios, swift

How should this be done in Swift?  The compiler error is "Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, NilLiteralConvertible)'"

```
    var request = NSURLRequest()
    if request.URL == nil {
    }
```

It seems like the normal pattern is to declare types optional when an object may not have a value.

However in this case I'm not sure why Apple did not declare the URL property as an optional var within the NSURLRequest class.

Comment: Looks like this works, but still not sure why the design pattern calls for non-optional if the value can be nil:   if request.URL as AnyObject? == nil { }

Comment: What's the intention? Are you wanting to assign an optional then check to see if it's assigned later? If so just initialize the request later and make it an optional.

Comment: The intention is really to understand how often nillable object -> Optional is an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this would be a pain in the normal (and only meaningful) use case. The normal use case is to call the designated initializer (`initWithURL:`), or something that calls the designated initializer with a real URL. So in all normal code, you'd have to unload the `NSURL?` every single time. That would get old fast for nothing.

If this were a from-scratch Swift object, then it would have no public `init()`, but you can't remove that because it's legal (though meaningless) ObjC. (Well, maybe they can remove it; that may be worth a radar to mark its `init()` private.)

So this is a compromise with ObjC-as-typically-programmed vs ObjC-as-legal-syntax. Many of the weirdnesses around calling Cocoa from Swift boil down to this.

If ObjC dev used `[[NSURLRequest alloc] init]` as a common pattern, then `URL` certainly would have been an optional. ObjC devs pretty much never do this, so it isn't.

As a note, if you're finding yourself in a case where `NSURLRequest()` seems useful, the really right answer is almost certainly to use an `NSURLRequest?` instead.

Comment: Good info.  It seems learning the interactions of Swift/ObjectiveC/Cocoa are more complex than learning the Swift language itself.

Comment: Much. Swift relies heavily on Cocoa. Cocoa is based on decades of ObjC history and culture. While I get the idea that people can learn Swift first, I think they're mistaken to think it will be *easy* without a background in ObjC.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Fortunately, request.URL.absoluteString is an optional. I think this will do what you need:

```
if (request.URL.absoluteString == nil) { ... }
```

Or, since NSMutableURLRequest uses an optional when URL is fetched, another option is to use NSMutableURLRequest() instead, if that works for your use case.

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest()
if (request.URL == nil) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. `URL` is a non-optional, read only variable of `NSURLRequest`.

If you stay in swift there is no way that this parameter can be nil. Unless you use the `NSURLRequest()` initializer, which is pretty pointless because URL is read-only and you can't set it.

Use one of the designated initializers. Or use `NSMutableURLRequest`, which has a `URL` variable that is not read-only and an optional.

Comment: `let request = NSURLRequest(); println(request.URL)` causes an error in Swift because `URL` is `nil`.

Comment: (Your solutions are correct, but your statement that "there is no way that this parameter can be nil" isn't.)

Comment: Yes, but why would you do this? A NSURLRequest without an URL is pointless.

Comment: I agree. I just mean that Swift's guarantee that objects exist if they aren't optional isn't a 100% guarantee.

Comment: Apple should probably throw an error in the plain `NSURLRequest()` initializer, though

Comment: Matthias' interpretation of this question is totally valid. I answered it in a different way above in a way that is intended to ensure the URL is non-empty. Since NSMutableURLRequest's URL variable is optional, its possible this one is meant to be optional too and that this is a bug in the framework.

Comment: Although... maybe it's really the empty initializer that's the bug ?? ... why does that even exist. Bizarro. Good point.

Comment: I agree. @MatthiasBauch I [opened a bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6424359535116288) to suggest a Swift error for the non-designated initializer in this case.